# array splice doesn't work with array formatted string (split string)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does array splice doesn't work with array formatted string? When I say array formatted string I mean I use `split()` to make string into array.

```js
function _formatText(text) {
  var textList = text.replace(/\s+/g, ",").split(",");
  return textList.splice(1, 0, "<br />").join(" ");
}

alert(_formatText("VERY VERY LONG TEXT"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method returns the array of removed elements, in your case it's empty array and you are applying join on the returned array.

So you need to rearrange it like this.

```js
function _formatText(text) {
  var textList = text.replace(/\s+/g, ",").split(",");
  textList.splice(1, 0, "<br />");
  return textList.join(" ");
}

alert(_formatText("VERY VERY LONG TEXT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the string replace method. With some reduced code you can also do like this.

```js
function _formatText(text) {
  var textList = text.split(/\s+/);
  return textList.slice(0,1).concat("</br>",textList.slice(1)).join(" ");
}

alert(_formatText("VERY VERY LONG TEXT"))
```